# "To persecute", but with a lighter acceptation, and without physical actions involved

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to indicate what someone is doing when they're *regularily* targeting anyone part of a different group / community using words and *without physical actions involved*, something like "to persecute" but with a lighter acceptation.

A good example would be supporters of a football teams (?) supporters of other teams; they're not "persecuting" each other, but if they meet they'd start (?) each other, so the topic is the rivalry here; nonetheless this wouldn't imply physical actions of any kind, but just words.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what options you've considered and rejected. For example, have you looked for synonyms of *persecute*?

Comment: _Rival football team supporters like to **antagonise** each other._

Comment: @JHCL Yes I did ([here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/persecute) to be precise), but none helped, since "to persecute" is not quite what I mean, although it's the closest I can get to express what I mean; both "to persecute" and its synonyms all seem to have a too heavy acceptation to describe what I'm really thinking; also the rivalry is the central topic, and I'd like this to stick out from the meaning somehow.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but *antagonise* is much better in the football situation (where provocation is a likely motive).

Comment: @JoeDark I quite like "to antagonise", it seems pretty close to what I mean, do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Not quite good for the sport fan context, but "harass" and "shun" work in other situations.

Comment: 'Persecute' has no racist connotations. It may very well be used in racist situations but does not, standing by itself, connote any kind of bigotry. Also I think you mean 'connotation' instead of 'acceptation' (I don't think the latter is a word)

Comment: [Barracking](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barrack) might be appropriate but it's more about the shouting than the ribbing...

Comment: You can use almost any word you want, as long as you include the phrase *all in good fun* or *all but*. E.g., "The bases loaded, the fans *all but* started murdering each other."

Answer (score 4):

**To heckle**

> Definition: To torment with persistent insult or ridicule; to harass
> (a public speaker, performer, etc.) with impertinent questions, gibes,
> or the like; to badger (to harass or urge persistently; pester; nag).
>
> Example: *As you correctly state, all members heckle from time to time
> and noise does get excessive and you do your best to try to quell
> that*.

**To hound**

> Definition: To pursue or harass without respite:
>
> Examples: *Her little brother
> wouldn't stop hounding her. When he is out of office, He is being
> hounded by the press*.

Eventually **To scold**

> Definition: to use harsh or abusive language; to criticize other
> people in an angry way; to heap abuse; to criticize or blame loudly
> and angrily.
>
> Example: *It wasn't Rick's fault he was late getting home,
> but his father didn't want to listen to his excuses; he just stood
> there and scolded*.

Also **to throw invectives [at each other]**

> Definition of "invective": Swearing or abusive language that is harsh
> or insulting; vehement accusations or denunciations including bitterly
> abusive or sarcastic speech.
>
> Example: *The politicians were throwing invectives at each other
> during their TV debate*.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [**Disparage**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disparage):

> to speak contemptuously of; belittle (-- Collins)

although it doesn't carry a confrontational aspect (you can *disparage* someone behind their back).

Comment: Indeed, apologizes, I didn't saw the edit coming in.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite close, +1, but the rivalry should really stick out here, I'd really like the reason behind (?) to be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

***Razzing***

*The Free Dictionary* "To deride, heckle, or tease: razzed the teammate who missed the shot"  Its derivation is "a shortening and tightening of raspberry."

*Collins Dictionary*: "the act of making fun of someone; ribbing, ragging;

The American team was subjected to sustained razzing by a section of the crowd.

It all started with a bit of friendly razzing.

He took a little razzing from his teammates."

Note that the second example from *Collins* suggests that razzing can escalate to something more serious.

Answer (score 1):

[***To shout (out)***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shout) can be a good candidate.

It means:

> To utter a sudden and loud outcry, as in joy, triumph, or exultation, or to attract attention, to animate soldiers, etc. [Wiktionary]

*Shout* as a noun means:

> A loud burst of voice or voices; a vehement and sudden outcry,
>   especially that of a multitude expressing joy, triumph, exultation, or
>   animated courage. [Wiktionary]

"They're not "persecuting" each other, but if they meet, they'd start (to shout at) each other."

Answer (score 1):

To **taunt**: "provoke or challenge (someone) with insulting remarks". http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taunt

Answer (score 0):

**Discriminate**: if you want to imply some prejudicial distinction towards another group, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well, not really, I was looking for something expressing e.g. what football players do when they trash talk to each other and all that sort of things, "unified" under a more general term.

Comment: Yes, I like **antagonise** as well. How about 'insult' or 'irritate' as alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

When rival fans meet, they start **leering** and **jeering** at each other.

*leer* : look or gaze in an unpleasant, malicious, or lascivious way –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=leering%20definition&oq=leering%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.54904j1j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

*jeer* : to speak or cry out with derision or mockery –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jeer)

---

Pivotal to the concept of *rivalry* and "regularly targeting anyone part of a different group", is the term *[Schadenfreude](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=schadenfreude)* (pleasure derived by someone from another person's misfortune). Animals who show themselves capable of herd mentality are biologically hardwired to participate in this type of 'group' behavior.

So, another word to indicate what someone is doing when *this* happens, is that they're experiencing schadenfreude. They're conforming to the group; reaping the chemical reward that their brains give them for participating 'socially'. Our tribal ingroup biases are human nature.

If you're interested, there's an excellent *Through the Wormhole* episode about all of this, especially concerning sports fans: *Are We All Bigots?* ([dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2ok6mk))

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is **barrack**, which means to shout at a public performer in order to indicate your dislike. It goes without saying that such behaviour often happens in the lead-up to football matches and during the matches themselves. As per the MacMillan dictionary:

> barrack - definition and synonyms
>
> VERB barrack pronunciation in British English /ˈbærək/
>
> 1 [INTRANSITIVE/TRANSITIVE] to shout at someone who is speaking, playing, or performing in public because you do not like them
>   He was barracked by supporters of the other team.